# Front end test automation

Tags: testing, automated-tests, frontend

I had to recently updgrade from jQuery 1.3 to 1.10. As a result lots jquery code was changed and plugins were upgraded. And consequently this resulted in lot of  hours of manual testing.
This got to me think that there should be a better way of testing/validating pages after any js/css change across my site.

I would like to do the following.

crawl all pages on my site.

Check all links on page work correctly

Check for basic html tag validation

Check for any JS & css errors.

jquery version compatible code

Any recommendations for tools that will allow me to perform all of the above test.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free tools exist for quite many of those tasks. There are both web page based validators and browser plugins. I don't know if some tool would do all the below in one or couple steps, but these should get you at least started.

- For crawling the site and checking all links you can use tool from [The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/):

  http://validator.w3.org/checklink

  The results page also provides links for for validating html and css of each page.
- If you want to validate a file otherwise, you can straight use

  http://validator.w3.org/

  and

  http://www.css-validator.org/
- For validating javascript syntax, you can use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html)
- Finally, if you want to be more sure that your javascript is working correctly, write unit tests for example with [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)